# How to git diff diverged branch

Tags: git, diff, git-branch, git-diff

I have re-written some commit history on my branch, so my branch has diverged from the remote one:

```
Switched to branch 'dev'
Your branch and 'origin/dev' have diverged,
and have 3 and 3 different commits each, respectively.
```

Is there an easy way to `git diff` between the diverged versions (i.e. my local branch and the remote branch)?

I know I can use `git diff commit1..commit2` to diff between 2 commits, but in this case I want to diff between the three local commits on my branch and the three remote commits.

Answer (score 2):

#### TL;DR

Use [`git range-diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-range-diff)—in this case, `git range-diff origin/dev...dev` (note the *three* dots here).

#### Long(ish)

First, let's draw the setup.  Here are the two sets of commits, as seen in your own repository:

```
          F'-G'-H'  <-- dev
         /
...--D--E
         \
          F--G--H   <-- origin/dev
```

The commits `F`, `G`, and `H`—the letters here stand in for the real hash IDs, which are too big and ugly to bother with—are the original three before you did your work; their new-and-improved replacements are F-prime, G-prime, and H-prime respectively.

It's very easy to compare the *end results* by comparing just those two commits: `git diff dev origin/dev` or `git diff origin/dev dev` will compare commits `H` and `H'` (`dev` selects `H'`, `origin/dev` selects `H`).  But this is not what you want, not really:

- You'd like to compare `F` vs `F'` first; then
- you would like to compare `G` vs `G'`; and finally
- you would like to compare `H` vs `H'`.

A single `git diff` command can only produce the last of these three.

The brute-force solution is to run three `git diff`s yourself, one at a time.  To name commit `F'`, you can write `dev~2`; to name commit `G'` you can write `dev~1` (or `dev~` or `dev^`—all of these work; see [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) for more information).  To name commit `F`, use `origin/dev~2`, and so on.

Ever since Git 2.19, though, there has been a new command that will *do this for you*.  As noted in the TL;DR above, that's `git range-diff`.

The range-diff command needs to know the two ranges to compare.  You can give them to it explicitly:

```
git range-diff origin/dev~3..origin/dev dev~3..dev
```

We use `~3` here, rather than `~2`, because ranges expressed with the two-dot `..` notation are half-open intervals mathematically: they include the final commit, but exclude the starting commit.  (Mentally you can just think of this as wanting three commits in the result, hence X~3..X.  The fact that this is (X~3 .. X] is important of course, since [X~3 .. X) would omit the wrong end of the range, but either way the half-open interval compensates for the usual [fencepost error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error#Fencepost_error).)  Again, see [gitrevisions](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions).

Even easier in this case, though, we can use the *three*-dot notation, which `git range-diff` handles slightly specially.  The three-dot notation, as described in the [gitrevisions](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) documentation, implies a *symmetric difference* oepration in terms of set theory, so that:

```
git range-diff origin/dev...dev
```

implies that the command should inspect commits reachable by *either* `origin/dev`—i.e., commits `H` on back—*or* `dev`, i.e., commits `H'` on back; but should *not* inspect commits reachable from *both names*, i.e., commits `E` and earlier.  So this selects exactly the desired two sets of commits: `F-G-H` and `F'-G'-H'`.

#### Fun with ranges

The remaining questions, then, are:

1. *How does this work?*  Why didn't we have to mention `X~3` anywhere, for some `X`?
2. *Are these in the right order?*  If not, you'll get a range-diff that describes going backwards, from your new-and-improved commits—probably resulting from a rebase—to the old-and-lousy ones.

Let's tackle question 1 first, then question 2.  We've actually answered question 1 already, but only by resorting to set theory, which might not be familiar to some.

[Symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) is defined in terms of sets: it's the union minus the intersection.  Given two sets *A* and *B*, the symmetric difference *A⊖B* or *A∆B* can be computed as the union of *A∖B* (read this as "A exclude B") and *B∖A* (or equivalently, as the result of subtracting the intersection *from* the union, which is how I normally think of it myself and stated it first here).

In the above, we wrote: *the set of all commits reachable from `dev`, excluding the set of all commits reachable from `dev~3`*.  That was our `dev~3..dev`.  That's a **very exact** way of stripping out *every commit starting at `E` and working backwards* from *every commit starting at `H'` and working backwards*.  But we don't have to be so exact after all.  We can be lazy, and say: *every commit starting at `H'` and working backwards, stripping out every commit starting at `H` and working backwards.*  While `F-G-H` aren't *in* that set, it's harmless to ask to strip them out of that set: *A∖B* doesn't require things in *B* to be in *A* in the first place.

So instead of `dev~3..dev`, we can use `origin/dev..dev` to strip out the commits from `E` on backwards.  Of course `origin/dev` is ten characters to type, while `dev~3` is just five, so we didn't really gain anything here.

The thing is, by the same token, we can write `dev..origin/dev` to exclude commits-backwards-from `E` from the commits backwards-from-H.  This time it *does* save some typing, and—even better—if we have some sort of notation that lets us just enter the two names for *A* and *B* here, we'll only have to type each name once.  **That's our symmetric difference notation** so we can type in just `origin/dev...dev` (three dots) or `dev...origin/dev` (still three dots).

Now let's tackle question 2, getting the right order.  We now consult [the `git range-diff` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-range-diff), which says:

> `<rev1>...<rev2>`
> Equivalent to passing `<rev2>..<rev1>` and `<rev1>..<rev2>`.

Now, originally I suggested:

```
git range-diff origin/dev~3..origin/dev dev~3..dev
```

That is, we put the *old* range of commits first, and the *new* range of commits second.  If we run:

```
git range-diff origin/dev...dev
```

then `<rev2>` is `dev`, so the "equivalent to" part comes to:

```
git range-diff dev..origin/dev origin/dev..dev
```

This uses the trick from item 1 to make the two separate range expressions, and makes sure the *second* range expression—which determines which commits are "new"—ends with the *second specified rev*, i.e., `dev`.  So `origin/dev...dev` is the correct order.

Answer (score 1):

After fetching with `git fetch` use

```
git diff <mainbranch_path> <remotebranch_path>
```

for example `git diff develop origin/develop`